# Best practice to persist HTML into database and output it

Tags: java, security, web, owasp

I have a input fields which allows users to enter in data that are saved into the database; in few usages, users can put in HTML.

Is the best practice to escape/encode the values (which may include html) when it's saved into db? or save as it and encode it during output?

EDIT: Just want to see if most people agree that encoding the text to be stored in the db is a bad idea explained by this [article](http://lukeplant.me.uk/blog/posts/why-escape-on-input-is-a-bad-idea/)

Comment: for more clearance can you share what you have tried yet.

Comment: You have two issues here. First is the SQL injection due to untrusted user input; second is the XSS when displaying the content. Wait for an answer that addresses both issues.

Answer (score 0):

It's always good to escape/encode user inputs before putting them into your database, otherwise you may expose system to SQL injection (that is if you are using any SQL DB).

Answer (score 0):

Escaping html specific characters is a standard practice. You can use [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/)

Simple example:

```
String htmlStr = "<h1>Hi</h1>"
StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(htmlStr);
```

This will encode the string as `&lt;h1&gt;Hi&lt;/h1&gt;`

Comment: My concern about storing the encoded version in the db is that now we  have transformed the data. This [article](http://lukeplant.me.uk/blog/posts/why-escape-on-input-is-a-bad-idea/) gives a detailed but long explanation about why it's bad to transform the stored data.

Comment: Its not bad but the argument in the article are worth considering if you are multiple output media.

Comment: If my app does have multiple output media, which it does, would you agree with the article's argument?